# How to easy create query like types : ( val1 + OR + val2 + OR + val3) with Spring Data Solr (With Dynamic Queries)

Tags: spring-data-solr

I have field "**types**" `multivalue=true.` 
From client layer I receive list of keys what should be processed.

I want to create FilterQuery to produce `fq` like `fq=types:(6+OR+4+OR+8)`

logically I expect to use next code:

```
final Criteria criteria = new Criteria("types").in(types);
new SimpleFilterQuery(criteria);
```

But this code produce `fq=types:(6+4+8)`

It could works, but I use `q.op=AND` (required for other needs)

Is it any simple way to do something like *inOr*/*inAny* ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found who ways, but this looks not so beauty as I expect:

First:

```
Criteria criteria = new SimpleStringCriteria("types:(" + StringUtils.join(statuses, " OR ") + ")");
new SimpleFilterQuery(criteria);
```

Second:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("types");
criteria.expression("(" + StringUtils.join(statuses, " OR ") + ")");
new SimpleFilterQuery(criteria);
```